# openerp 6.1 client freezing (not responding)

Tags: odoo

I installed the openerp client 6.1 from the nightly on windows xp and windows7 and the 6.1 server on a linux (debian) from debian apt repository. 
I was able to connect wit pgAdmin to the database but when I try to connect with the openerp GTK client its not working. 
The client is freezing and not responding any more.

lsof say the server is on and listening on all interfaces on 8067 and 8070.

how can I check if the openerp server is working well?

I suppose its a server issue because the server don't shutdown clean, I needed to give him kill -9. But when I shot down the server the client was not freezing any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like its a Linux version issue.
I reinstalled the server with UBUNTU and I do not have this freezing any more.
Strange behavior.